# Shell script, parallel and multithreaded?

Tags: linux, multithreading, shell, parallel-processing

I have a shell script which actually has file/folder locations and command to run a javascript. I am running the job on a linux cluster with 8 processors and 4 CPU cores per processor. I want to run this on multiple processors, at the same time each job accessing multiple threads to reduce the total runtime of the script.  My question is:
Is such a thing possible? If yes what would be the command or code snippet for this?

Comment: Can you show the code that you want to run? Also, to clarify, are we talking about 8 separate linux machines with access to the same filesystem? What does your code produce?

Comment: thecontents of the shell script is as follows: ts=ts/
out=ers/
db=db/
ks=ks/
ids=list/ids
que=que/


bin/java -Xmx2400M -classpath java/class/ FEP "$@" -db $db -ks $ks -ids $ids -que $que -ts $ts -out $out >$log 2>&1

Comment: I try running my script with: nohup ss.sh > &p &        where p I keep from 1000 to 50,000. This way it shows just 1/8 cpus being used somewhere close to 100%. I presume (am not sure though) that this way it uses p no of threads on one CPU.

Comment: I have also separately tried running using:              #!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 32)
do
        ( scripts/findEpitopePartners1.sh nosurf seqintonly >&100 )
   if (( $i % 20 == 0)); then wait; fi
done
wait
                                                                                                                              I found this in one of the threads in stackoverflow, which inturn launches 20 instances of the javascript but the processes individually run too slow.

Comment: I'm not sure how `nohup` or `> &p` are going to produce multiple instances, and at the moment you're still just running a single Java process. Does this Java process handle all of the files sequentially? What you want to do is call a different Java instance for each file that you want to run on. I still don't quite understand what the process is doing, or how you want to split the threads. There are some number of files, each of which need processing, right?

Comment: forget about the javascript.                                                                Putting it simply I have a ss.sh script which I want to run in parallel on more than one cpu. A job at each cpu using more than one thread.

Comment: If you want ss.sh to run in more than one thread then you need to split the process into things that can be run independently. As far as I can tell, you will need to change the Java to run only a portion of the whole task, and run a load of copies of it.

Comment: yeah the java is capable enough of running on more than one cpu. I have already checked that. The final output which actually is a set of files, running in parallel say 20 at a time leads to the creation of 20 files in one go.

Comment: So the Java is already running multithreaded? Why do you need to do anything to the shell script?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use [GNU `parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/GNU-Parallel.html).  Example:

```
parallel "zcat {} | bzip2 >{.}.bz2 && rm {}" ::: *.gz
```

*"This will recompress all files in the current directory with names ending in .gz using bzip2, running one job per CPU (-j+0) in parallel."*

---

If you don't have parallel, then you can roll your own coordinator in a couple of ways:

1. Use [`make -j`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Parallel)
2. Use bash in-built backgrounding (`&`)

You can use `ssh` for running commands on remote machines, and you can use `nfs` or its ilk for networked storage.  However you do it, you will need to think about how to partition your jobs so that they can cooperate and, as needed, coalesce results.

Comment: I have just user level permissions on this cluster, meaning I cannot install a program that needs root permission. I had read on this GNU parallel thing but as I type in parallel .... I get an error message parallel command not found

Comment: You don't need `parallel` to run multiple jobs from a shell script, although it does make it easier. Putting `&` at the end of a line in a shell script will continue without waiting for the line to finish. That doesn't help with multiple machines though. If you show the code we might be able to help.

Comment: @user4880140 Download the parallel source code to your home directory, build it, then run it from your local build.  Alternatively, roll your own the hard way.

Comment: On GNU, *BSD and OSX you can also use `xargs -P`